# angular guard-service inject service

Tags: angular, service, guard

I need to inject a service in a guard. This guard checks if the user was invited, when yes, he can access the route.

To check this condition, I need to call a service which fetches this information from the db.

I have a cyclical dependency error, I understand that we shouldn't inject services in Guards, but in this case, I need to do it:

```
  providers: [AuthService, HackService, HacksStorageService, AuthGuard, EmailGuard],
```

And the guard:

```
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate } from "../../../node_modules/@angular/router";
import { HacksStorageService } from "../shared/hacks-storage.service";

export class EmailGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private hacksStorageService: HacksStorageService,
  ) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.hacksStorageService.fetchHack();
    // check if user was invited. should be in the participants array
    return true;
  }
}
```

I am pretty confused. Usually I used guards to see if user is logged in or not, so I usually imported stuff from firebase, not from my own services, so not cyclical dependencies.

Now I want to check if a condition happens, based on my own data. How can I inject my own data in the EmailGuard, if I am not allowed to inject services because of the cyclical dependency?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by injecting data in `EmailGurad`? And also provide your `AuthGuard` inside routing module instead of app or any feature module.

Comment: i want to inject the hacksStorageService into my EmailGuard. i need that, since the hacksStorageService has a method which gives me back and object. once I have the object, i can check a condition

Comment: You can inject services to guards, there's no problem with that, but you just can't have a cyclic dependency, so you have to solve it in a way where it doesn't happen :)

Comment: I am very, sorry, I forgot the @Injectable. When I saw that my guard could not be created, I immediately thought about cyclical dependency. Thank you all for your help and sorry again. ADMINS, should I delete the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject services in guards.
If your service returns synchronously, then you can just return immediately, like in your sample code.
Otherwise, I did it like this (using firebase auth)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Paths } from './paths';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignInGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      return this.afAuth.user.pipe(
        first(),
        map(user => {
          if (user) {
            this.router.navigate([Paths.MAIN_PATH]);
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        })
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is deprecated. The CanActivate interface has been deprecated, to be more precise.

Answer (score 4):

The current solution can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn):

```
const canActivateTeam: CanActivateFn = 
  (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
    return inject(PermissionsService).canActivate(inject(UserToken), route.params.id);
  };
```